# Spawn Sprites on Desktop [Haxe Flixel]

Tags: openfl, haxeflixel, lime

I am trying to **spawn sprites on the desktop**, the same way you would in a regular HaxeFlixel State.

Kinda like the [desktop goose](https://samperson.itch.io/desktop-goose) from a while back.

I have *already tried to do this* effect with **boarder-less windows** but it just isn’t rendering sprites correctly.

I was woundering if anyone had a **different solution** to this problem!

Better example of what I mean:

[This!](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/971887840378093568/971896642963910716/GASTER.mp4)

This video is a animation.

**Thank you all!**

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlxSprite.

```
var sprite = new FlxSprite
```

https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxSprite.html

Comment: Completely not what I mean, I mean outside the games application.